# Tensorflow 1.12: compute the derivative of elements in one tensor with respect to elements in another tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I have a b-by-T-by-n tensor Z, and a n-by-m matrix X, and I wish to compute the partial derivative of every element in Z with respect to every element in X that share the same index along the axis with size n. Hence, my output would be a b-by-T-by-n-by-m tensor.

Is there a built-in function or an efficient way to do so in Tensorflow? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into `tf.gradients`?

Comment: tf.gradients() compute the derivative of a scalar with respect to a tensor, so it is not what I'm looking for. tf.Jacobian(Z,X) is a bit closer to what I'm looking for but not exactly what I am looking for, because it computes the gradient of every element in Z with respect to every element in X, whereas I only want to compute the gradient of z_{b,t,j} with respect to x_{j,i} for indicies b, t, j and i.